# Creating a hyperlink from command line output on a terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, 21.10

The command `hostnamectl`, when executed with no argument, will dump a bunch of information to the terminal. One of that is the `Operating System` line as shown in the sample output below:

```
$ hostnamectl  
 Static hostname: xxxxxx
       Icon name: computer-laptop
         Chassis: laptop
      Machine ID: e8..43
         Boot ID: 7b..2a
Operating System: Ubuntu 21.10
          Kernel: Linux 5.13.0-28-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: XXXXXX
  Hardware Model: XXXXXX
```

However, the output "`Ubuntu 21.10`" is underlined like a hyperlink and when you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click, it will open a web browser with the following link address: `https://ubuntu.com/`.

How is this accomplished? What are the terminal commands (*escape sequences*?) that I need to output from a text based program or script to create such a hyperlink on the terminal?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This information was not present in **Ask Ubuntu**, but I found the answer in another site: https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda

The *escape sequence* to create the above link is:

```
printf '\e]8;;https://ubuntu.com/\e\\Ubuntu 21.10\e]8;;\e\\\n'
```

The general format is:

1. The hyperlink **open sequence** starts with

- the `\e]8` *escape sequence* (<kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd>, and <kbd>8</kbd>),
- the *params*,
- the *target URI*, and
- the closing `\e\` *escape sequence* (<kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>\</kbd>)

where `params` is optional:  `\e]8;params;URI\e\\`

2. Then comes the *content* that will be painted as hyperlink.
3. The hyperlink is **closed** with the same escape sequence (as in step 1), however omitting *params* and the *URI*, but keeping the separators: `\e]8;;\e\\`

---

As a bonus to this answer, I suggest you use the following alias in your `~/.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias ll="LC_COLLATE=C ls --hyperlink=auto --group-directories-first --color=auto -alF"
```

Here, the `--hyperlink` argument will direct the `ls` command to automatically create *hyperlinks* for file names on terminal output, so that when they are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+clicked they will open in *Nautilus* or the associated application.